How to use search funtionality similar to ctrl+f using react-virtualized
I have a use case where I want to display a dynamic sized content with millions of rows using scrollbar which I am doing using react-virtualized list.
Is there a way to perform search on this list (using Ctrl+F)?
Is there any existing library or an easier way to highlight all the places where the given search keyword exists and use enter to navigate to next instance of the search keyword?
Or is there any way to integrate the react-virtualized with react-codemirror to use the codemirror search functionality?
Did not find any existing implementation of the same.
